Azure OpenAI Assistant API - send prompt as a result of function calling - @azure/openai-assistants
I'm using Assistant Api to get list of projects from my API in the json format.
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "2024-05-08T18:11:45.099Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-05-08T18:11:45.095Z",
    "name": "Purchase",
  },
{
    "id": 2,
    "createdAt": "2024-05-08T18:11:45.099Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-05-08T18:11:45.095Z",
    "name": "Sales",
  },
]

I have declared a function to my assistant api:
{
    type: "function" as const,
    function: {
      name: "getProjects",
      description:
        "Get list of projects in a json format which needs to be additionally filtered by area parameter. After calling this function, filter it additionally with area by finding projects that correspond to this name",
      parameters: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          environment: {
            type: "string",
            description: "environment",
          },
          area: {
            type: "string",
            description: "The area of projects",
          },
        },
        required: [],
      },
    },
    handler: async ({ environment, area }: { environment: string; area: string }) => {
      if (!environment) return "environment param missing. Ask user to provide it";
      if (!area) return "area param missing. Ask user to provide it";

      const projects = await client.getProjects();

      const projectsPrompt = `Filter the following list of projects by ${area}: ${JSON.stringify(projects)}`;

      return projectsPrompt;
    },
  },

Then I'm passing the result into toolsOutput and call
runResponse = await assistantsClient.submitToolOutputsToRun(
              runResponse.threadId,
              runResponse.id,
              toolOutputs,
            );

Additionally in the instructions for assistant I put:

If user asks for projects, make sure to filter them out by area
parameter. E.g if user passes Sales area, you should find projects in
the response of a function and find only projects related to Sales

Now after sending a message

Give me list of projects in Sales area and dev env

I'm getting
Here is the list of projects in the Sales area and dev environment:
Purchase
Sales
Please let me know if there's anything else I can assist you with.

But instead I want the model to filter out the projects so it displays only Sales.
If in the next message I say that it's wrong, it's corrected fine.
If I take json with projects as a string and put it directly in the message and ask to filter it, it will do it correctly. So it looks like sending prompt as an output of a tool doesn't work. Is there a way to ask the model to do something with the result of my function?
